# LaTex with wrong graph arrangement (Wrong position)

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I want to build LaTex like the first photo but I make it become the second.

What is the method to fit the code to the first graph? Thanks for your help.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
\begin{document}  
\begin{figure}  

\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-golden} 

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't ignore errors, `&` is only allowed inside a tabular. Beside this: replace the graphics with dummy images, e.g. `example-image`, then we can compile your code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer
Hi, I have replaced it with dummy images and hope you can help compile my code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit unclear what you actually want, but perhaps something like this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\tabcolsep=0pt \tiny
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
\begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
\includegraphics[width=0.0625\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.0625\textwidth]{example-image-golden} \\[-\dp\strutbox]
\includegraphics[width=0.0625\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.0625\textwidth]{example-image-golden} 
\end{tabular}&
\includegraphics[width=0.125\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.125\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.125\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.125\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.125\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.125\textwidth]{example-image-golden} &
\includegraphics[width=0.125\textwidth]{example-image-golden}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]